# Pushing Data from Django API to Mixed Chart.js in an Interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, chart.js2

I have a problem displaying data into a mixed bar and line chart from an API designed using the Django Rest Framework. Here is the model for the readings from the pressure and flowrate sensors

```
models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ReadingQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class ReadingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ReadingQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Reading(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    pressure =models.IntegerField(default=0)
    flowrate =models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp =models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ReadingManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.timestamp) + ' ' + 'Pressure: ' + str(self.pressure) + ' ' + 'Flowrate: ' + str(self.flowrate)
```

The code for the serializer is here.

```
serializers.py 

from rest_framework import serializers

from app.models import Reading

class ReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reading
        fields = ['id','date','timestamp','pressure','flowrate']
```

the serializer is in an api folder i placed within a django app. the code for the APIview is below.

```
  views.py

from rest_framework import generics, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import ReadingSerializer
from app.models import Reading
    class ReadingChartAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
        permission_classes = []
        authentication_classes = []
        serializer_class = ReadingSerializer

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            qs = Reading.objects.all()
            data = {
                'timestamp':qs.values('timestamp'),
                'pressure':qs.values('pressure'),
                'flowrate':qs.values('flowrate'),
                'update':qs.values('pressure', 'flowrate').last()
            }
            return Response(data)

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and this is the data i receive from the APIview

```
{"timestamp":[{"timestamp":"12:44:11.487901"},{"timestamp":"14:12:58.410520"},{"timestamp":"01:56:56.485449"},{"timestamp":"01:57:14.184429"},{"timestamp":"01:57:34.366559"},{"timestamp":"13:12:43.469454"}],"pressure":[{"pressure":45},{"pressure":35},{"pressure":79},{"pressure":52},{"pressure":89},{"pressure":27}],"flowrate":[{"flowrate":56},{"flowrate":67},{"flowrate":83},{"flowrate":14},{"flowrate":74},{"flowrate":46}],"update":{"pressure":27,"flowrate":46}}
```

The issue is in my html file when i am extracting this data. Here is my HTML.I am stuck and open to any solutions. i am trying to push the data labels for to datasets every after 5 seconds starting from the first one.

```
    {% extends "layouts/base.html" %}
{%load static %}

{% block title %} Dashboard {% endblock %} 

<!-- Specific Page CSS goes HERE  -->
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock stylesheets %}

{% block content %}
{% block jquery %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  var counter = 0
  var limit = 6
  var chart = $('#myChart')
  var endpoint = '/api/chart'
  var pressures = []
  var flowrates = []
  var timestamps = []
  var pressure_new = []
  var flowrate_new = []
  $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: endpoint,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)


      }
  })
  var getData =
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: endpoint,
      success: function(data){
        timestamps = data.timestamp.map(b => b.timestamp);
        pressures = data.pressure.map(a => a.pressure);
        flowrates = data.flowrate.map(c => c.flowrate);
        myChart.data.labels.concat(timestamps[counter]);
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data.concat(pressures[counter]);
        myChart.data.datasets[1].data.concat(flowrates[counter]);
        counter++;
        myChart.update();
      }
    });
  setInterval(getData, 3000)
</script>
{% endblock %}
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="page-header row no-gutters py-4">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-left mb-0">
        <span class="text-uppercase page-subtitle">Dashboard</span>
        <h3 class="page-title">Overview</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-4">
        <div class="card" width = '18rem' height = '10rem'>
          <div class="card-header border-bottom">
             <h5 class="card-title">Pressure and Flowrate</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-1 text-muted">Real-time Readings of Pressure and Flowrate</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
            <script>
              function setChart(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Pa',
                            data:[],
                            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            borderColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }, {
                          label: 'cm3/min',
                          data:[],
                          backgroundColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                          borderColor:'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                          type: 'line',

                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
              };
              setChart()
            </script>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```